# angular2 and ionic2 catch gestures event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I wonder if it is possible to catch gestures with ionic2 (angular2 and typescript)
in the following way:

Let's say that I have 2 lists like that:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col width-25>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{ user.name }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-col>

  <ion-col width-25 offset-25>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{ item.name }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

What I would like to do is to be able to catch the event of dragging an item to a specific user.

Is it possible or did I go too far?

Comment: I think you would probably have to use some sort of a drag and drop library. Thankfully one of my favorite drag and drop libraries works for ionic 2: https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-drag-and-drop/ in fact, in their example, they're doing exactly what you want to do. Drag an item from one list to another.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on a mobile device does the drag&drop work for non-mouse platforms?